# Next.js Image component error src missing

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have the following error occurring when I attempt to use the next.js image component.

```
Error: Image is missing required "src" property. Make sure you pass "src" in props to the `next/image` component. Received: {}
```

The `src` value being passed in is:

```
https://res.cloudinary.com/mward82/images/q_auto:eco/v1616884491/1E3EDA11-D657-4FBD-8123-EFE0C5F43AC8_idzuc7/1E3EDA11-D657-4FBD-8123-EFE0C5F43AC8_idzuc7.webp
```

I can confirm this when I use `img` instead of `Image`.

The following is the code in question, from `components/cover-image.js`

```
import cn from "classnames";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function CoverImage({ title, coverImage, slug }) {
  const image = (
    <Image
      src={coverImage?.sourceUrl}
      height={coverImage?.mediaDetails.height}
      width={coverImage?.mediaDetails.width}
      className={cn("shadow-small", {
        "hover:shadow-medium transition-shadow duration-200": slug
      })}
    />
  );
  console.log(coverImage);
  return (
    <div className="sm:mx-0">
      {slug ? (
        <Link as={`/posts/${slug}`} href="/posts/[slug]">
          <a aria-label={title}>{image}</a>
        </Link>
      ) : (
        image
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

My `next.config.js` files contains the following:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ["res.cloudinary.com"]
  }
};
```

You can see a forked copy of my sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/script-hungryvercelapp-forked-7wd9e

Comment: Rather annoyingly, this works outside of the sandbox when deployed to vercel :/

Comment: does coverImage prop value is dependent on API?

Comment: Yes. It’s coming from a headless Wordpress install

Comment: So, what must be happening that till then the value of coverImage is here, this component is rendered and the src value of the Image component is empty

Comment: If I change to using img then all is good, Image not so much. And it all works when deployed to production on vercel which is frustrating as I need it to work in the sandbox too.

Comment: See img is a HTML element and Image is NextJS component, both works differently.

Comment: Not sure why this works fine on production, but these were my findings. Try to conditionally render the component based on coverImage value and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Understood. But this doesn’t explain why it does work when on production in vercel. See https://script-hungry.vercel.app

Comment: Thank you. Will do some more investigating

Comment: Changing `{ image }`  to `{ coverImage && image }` works in codesandbox. Just not sure why...

Comment: Great... The reason must be that only I think which I have mentioned in above comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my page was listing posts that don’t contain images. Modifying the code in `components/cover-image.js` to check for the existence of `coverImage` solved the problem.

The two references to `image` in the return section were changed to `coverImage && image` so that the `image` component rendered conditionality based on the existence of `coverImage`.

This is the working `components/cover-image.js`:

```
import cn from "classnames";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function CoverImage({ title, coverImage, slug }) {
  const image = (
    <Image
      src={coverImage?.sourceUrl}
      height={coverImage?.mediaDetails.height}
      width={coverImage?.mediaDetails.width}
      className={cn("shadow-small", {
        "hover:shadow-medium transition-shadow duration-200": slug
      })}
    />
  );
  console.log(coverImage);
  return (
    <div className="sm:mx-0">
      {slug ? (
        <Link as={`/posts/${slug}`} href="/posts/[slug]">
          <a aria-label={title}>{coverImage && image}</a>
        </Link>
      ) : (
        coverImage && image
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks to Yash Sangai for pushing me in the correct direction.